# Need help on a memoization recursion-like way to complete this task

Tags: python, recursion, mathematical-optimization, pseudocode

I am working on the following problem and I really want to do it in a recursion like way cause it seems that it can be done if memoization is added. Pseudo code would fine.

The problem is:

Showing the step-by-step to change a set of three numbers (a,b,c) to a desired set of three numbers following these rules.

**Rule 1. Incease 2 in one of a,b,c, the left two both decrease 1**

**Rule 2. Increase 1 in two of a,b,c, the left one decrease 2**

**Rule 3. If applying the above rule would cause one of a,b,c less than zero, then it would remain the same before applying the rule.**

For example:

if (a,b,c) is applyed with rule 1 with a increasing, it would become(a+2,b-1,c-1),unless b or c is 0.

if (a,b,c) is applyed with rule 2 with b,c increasing, it would become(a-2,b+1,c+1),unless a is less than 2.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO, when you ask a question please mention (code) of what you have tried so far. This way community will be able to help you more.

Comment: Python or just pseudo code would be fine. I did tried python but it seems when storing the tuple (a,b,c)as a dictonary key there are some key value error. Also since I need to output the step by step of moving I am not sure how to do this.